# Is it possible to use a reduction variable from a passed-by-pointer argument inside an orphaned C routine?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

I'm trying to have a reduction variable inside an orphaned routine in C. I realise that I need to pass the variable by pointer to the routine to ensure it is treated as shared (it is shared in the enclosing parallel region). However, when I try and compile the compiler doesn't like the fact that the variable is a pointer (I think) and complains it does not have a reduction type for pointers, i.e. with the cray compiler I get this error:

```
CC-1642 craycc: ERROR File = main.c, Line = 33
  The OpenMP reduction clause does not accept pointer or reference types.
  #pragma omp for reduction(+:sum)
```

When using this example code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<omp.h>

int myroutine(double *, double *, int);

int main(void){

  double a[100];
  double sum;
  int i;
  int n = 100;

  for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    a[i]=3.2;
  }


#pragma omp parallel shared(a,n,sum)
{
  myroutine(a, &sum, n);
}

  printf("sum = %lf\n",sum);

  return 0;
}

int myroutine(double *a, double *sum, int n){

  int i;

#pragma omp for reduction(+:sum)
  for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    *sum += a[i];
  }

  return 0;

}
```

Do I need to do some copying from the passed by pointer variable to a local variable? Or is there some other way to achieve this?

Comment: As a side note: You never initialized `double sum;`.

Comment: The error message is about the `#pragma omp for reduction(+:sum)`.   By definition, pragmas are compiler-specific extensions.   You'll need to read the documentation for your compiler to be sure how to fix.   However, my guess is that you'll need to create a local variable  (I'll call it `x`) in the function, initialise it to zero, and change all references to `sum` in the pragma and the loop to `x`.    Then, after the loop, add a statement `*sum = x`.

Comment: Thanks @Peter, I'm am asking about the specifics of the OpenMP pragma definitions in C. For Fortran the above would be fine, but for C the pass-by-reference thing is causing issues.

Comment: Good spot @mch, that's embarrasing, but shouldn't affect this compilation issue

Comment: @AdrianJackson - understand that.   But, understand that `sum` is a pointer and `*sum` is a reference, and the error message is saying  the reduction clause can't use a pointer or a reference.    The only other logical possibility is that it must be supplied the name of a variable.   So create one and use it.

Comment: @Peter, `*sum` is *not* a reference.  C does not have references.  The message appears to be generic, serving also for C++ and maybe Fortran, but `*sum` would not be a reference in C++, either.  But that just means that the "reference" part of the message does not speak to the alternative of using `*sum` in the reduction, not that doing so would be accepted.

Comment: @Peter OpenMP is a well-defined standard implemented by various compilers. Although it could improve the question to include the compiler version that is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int myroutine(double *a, double *sum, int n)
{
    int i;
    static double localSum = *sum;

#pragma omp for reduction(+:localSum)
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        localSum += a[i];
    }
    *sum = localSum;

    return 0;
}
```

works, but is gross and horrible, since it would break if you tried it from separate teams in a nested parallel region. (Though its safe if you're not using nested parallelism, and not starting OpenMP from independent pthreads, which is almost the same thing!)

I would hope that something like

```
 #pragma omp for reduction(+:sum[0])
```

would work in OpenMP 5.0 where array sections are supported in reductions, but unfortunately compilers probably aren't there yet (understandably, since the specification  is not yet finalized!)

Comment: I believe you are confusing OpenMP 4.5 and OpenMP 5.0. However `sum[0]` is not an array section as per OpenMP 4.5. 2.4. So it is an array element or array item. While the standard explicitly allows array sections, I cannot find a reference to array elements/items.

Comment: Thanks, that was what I feared, but at least it's a solution.

Answer (score 0):

A naked pointer is ambiguous in that situation - the compiler cannot know that it is a single value, it could also be multiple. However, you can use a simple **array section** with one element to help out the compiler:

```
#pragma omp for reduction(+:sum[:1])
```

This works since OpenMP 4.5 - which is fortunately supported by the Cray compiler. I tested with GCC 8.2.0

P.S. Jim's suggested `sum[0]` also seems to work with GCC, but I am unsure what to make of it. I cannot find any explicit reference to array elements (or array items which include array elements as per the OpenMP glossary) in the reduction documentation.

Comment: And now @AdrianJackson is switching the accepted answer - what is wrong here?

Comment: Both Clang and icc reject this approach (see https://godbolt.org/z/4JwPYu ) on the grounds that "the reduction variable ("sum") must be shared". It's not clear to me whether that is correct or not (and, as above, I prefer this solution in general, but it's not much use if the compilers don't like it :-().

Comment: p.s. Bugs submitted to LLVM and the Intel compilers :-)